# R - Count observations (strings) in a column and calculate as a percentage of overall observations

Tags: r, count, percentage

Hi Have some data that looks like this:

```
ID   Item     Class  Value  Date
1    Eggs     A      5      07/07/21
2    Eggs     A      4.5    07/07/21
3    Cereal   C      2      07/07/21
4    Eggs     B      3.5    07/07/21
5    Bread    B      2.5    07/07/21
6    Juice    A      3      07/07/21
7    Juice    C      1.5    07/07/21
8    Eggs     C      2      07/07/21
9    Bread    A      3      07/07/21
10   Juice    A      3      07/07/21
```

This is just a sample, the actual data has around 8k rows (and there are 300+ dataframes). I want to create a new df that

1. calculates the percentage of observations in the `Item` column (e.g. there are 10 items in the column, four of which are `Eggs`, thus the percentage of `Eggs` is 40)
2. calculates the average `Value` of each `Item` group

Ideally, the final data would look something like this:

```
Item    Percentage  Average_Value  Date
Eggs    40          3.75           07/07/21
Cereal  10          2              07/07/21
Bread   20          2.75           07/07/21
Juice   30          2.5            07/07/21
```

A couple of things to note - I want to do this to 300+ different csv's (where my data is stored) and create a single df with this new information. Each csv refers to a different date, so the final df would look something like the above, only with another four lines, but with different values and a different date. I know that I'll need to use a for loop for that, and maybe I should figure that part out later, but thought it was worth mentioning now. Finally, at some point, I might want to also calculate the average value of `Class`. Would I be better of making a separate df for this as I can't see how else I could do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do these steps in `tidyverse`

- set working directory to directory where your 300+ csv files are stored
- read all 300+ csv names into `temp`
- assuming each csv name refers to your `date` else you have to tweak the code a little bit
- using `map` and `imap_dfr` as explained below you can execute the same code for each file only once and as a result you'll have a single dataframe

```
setwd('my/path/here')

temp <- list.files(pattern = '*.csv')

library(tidyverse)

map(temp, read.csv) %>% setNames(gsub('.csv', '', temp)) %>%
  imap_dfr(~ .x %>% group_by(item) %>%
         summarise(Percentage = n()/nrow(df)*100, 
                   Average_Value = mean(Value), .groups = 'drop') %>%
         mutate(Date = .y))
```

---

If instead all your csvs contain date column do this

```
map_dfr(temp, ~read.csv(.x) %>% group_by(item, date) %>%
          summarise(Percentage = n()/nrow(df)*100, 
                    Average_Value = mean(Value), .groups = 'drop'))
```

Comment: Thanks so much @AnilGoyal. Works perfectly. Do you have any idea how I would also add a column with the count of Items (as well as the percentage)?

Comment: @Japes, yes!  can you show me a few lines how one of your file is? and how it is named?

Comment: Would it be best to continue this in private chat? I have limited characters here to write out the sample data! :)

Comment: @Japes, you can mail me

Answer (score 1):

You can `merge` the result of `proportions` of `table` with the result form `aggregate` of the `mean`of `Value ~ Item`. In case the `Date` also need to be there, this could be added using `cbind` or `data.frame`.

```
merge(aggregate(cbind(Average_Value = Value) ~ Item, x, mean)
    , proportions(table(x$Item))*100
    , by.y=1, by.x="Item")[c(1,3,2)]
#    Item Freq Average_Value
#1  Bread   20          2.75
#2 Cereal   10          2.00
#3   Eggs   40          3.75
#4  Juice   30          2.50
```

Or using only `aggregate`:

```
aggregate(Value ~ Item, x, function(y) c(Freq=length(y)/nrow(x)*100, Average=mean(y)))
#    Item Value.Freq Value.Average
#1  Bread      20.00          2.75
#2 Cereal      10.00          2.00
#3   Eggs      40.00          3.75
#4  Juice      30.00          2.50
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the suggestion. I ended up using the dplyr / summarise / group_by method (mainly because it's a bit shorter), but I'm sure this works too :)

Answer (score 1):

Does this work:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(Item) %>% summarise(Percentage = n()/nrow(df)*100, Average_Value = mean(Value))
# A tibble: 4 x 3
  Item   Percentage Average_Value
  <chr>       <dbl>         <dbl>
1 Bread          20          2.75
2 Cereal         10          2   
3 Eggs           40          3.75
4 Juice          30          2.5
```

Comment: This works perfectly, thanks! The only other thing I need to do is add the date column. Any thoughts on how to do this? I'm sure it's probably very simple, but programming isn't my forte!

Comment: @Japes, if you need `Date` column as well then try: `df %>% group_by(Item, Date) %>% summarise(Percentage = n()/nrow(df)*100, Average_Value = mean(Value))`

Comment: Brilliant, works like a charm, thanks! If I could be so bold as to ask one more thing... If I also want to calculate the avg of another column, let's call it `value2` (again, it would be grouped by `Item`), how would I add that to this line of code? Basically, can I calculate the averages of two columns in one line of code?

Comment: False alarm, figured it out through trial and error. Posting here incase it's useful for anyone else: `df %>% group_by(Item, Date) %>% summarise(Percentage = n()/nrow(df)*100, Average_Value = mean(Value),Average_Value2 = mean(Value2))`

Answer (score 0):

List all the files that you want to use using `list.files`. Combine them in one file using `map_df` and for each `Date` calculate the percentage of `Item` present and it's average value.

```
library(tidyverse)

filenames <- list.files(pattern = '\\.csv$')

map_df(filenames, read_csv) %>%
  group_by(Date, Item) %>%
  summarise(Percentage = n(), 
            Average_Value = mean(Value)) %>%
  mutate(Percentage = prop.table(Percentage) * 100) %>%
  ungroup -> result

result
```